# Zod inferred union type does not work properly: 'hackerProfile' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, zod

My Zod inferred union type does not work properly; 'hackerProfile' does not exist on type...

Typescript is telling me that `hackerProfile`, `partnerProfile`, and `mentorProfile` don't exist on my UpdateUserInput, which I inferred from Zod.

Even though I can see `hackerProfile`, `partnerProfile`, and `mentorProfile` in the type when I hoer my cursor over it in VS code. It doesn't seem to have a problem with `userUpdate`.

What's going on here?

`server/src/utils/validators.ts`

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const userUpdateValidator = z.object({
  firstName: z.string().optional(),
  lastName: z.string().optional(),
  website: z.string().optional(),
  rules: z.boolean().optional(),
  linkedin: z.string().optional(),
});

const ethExpValidator = z.union([
  z.literal('beginner'),
  z.literal('intermediate'),
  z.literal('advanced'),
  z.literal(''),
]);

const motiavtionValidator = z.union([
  z.literal(''),
  z.array(
    z.union([
      z.literal('workshop'),
      z.literal('resume'),
      z.literal('improve'),
      z.literal('jobOps'),
      z.literal('meetPpl'),
      z.literal('launchProduct'),
      z.literal('winPrize'),
      z.literal('other'),
    ])
  ),
]);

const textAreaValidator = z.union([
  z.string().min(250).max(500),
  z.literal(''),
]);

const updateHackerValidator = z.object({
  userUpdate: userUpdateValidator,
  hackerProfile: z.object({
    github: z.string().optional(),
    yearsOfExp: z.number().min(0),
    ethExp: ethExpValidator,
    motivation: motiavtionValidator,
    builtBefore: textAreaValidator,
    lookingToBuild: textAreaValidator,
  }),
});

const updatePartnerValidator = z.object({
  userUpdate: userUpdateValidator,
  partnerProfile: z.object({
    organization: z.string().optional(),
    telegram: z.string().optional(),
    twitter: z.string().optional(),
    otherEvents: textAreaValidator,
    reasonForSupporting: textAreaValidator,
  }),
});

const updateMentorValidator = z.object({
  userUpdate: userUpdateValidator,
  mentorProfile: z.object({
    telegram: z.string().optional(),
    twitter: z.string().optional(),
    yearsOfExp: z.number(),
    ethExp: ethExpValidator,
    otherEvents: textAreaValidator,
    reasonForMentoring: textAreaValidator,
  }),
});

// tried this as well
// export const updateUserValidator = z.union([
export const updateUserValidator = z.discriminatedUnion('userUpdate', [
  updateHackerValidator,
  updatePartnerValidator,
  updateMentorValidator,
]);

export type UpdateUserInput = z.infer<typeof updateUserValidator>;

export type UpdateMentorInput = z.infer<typeof updateMentorValidator>;
export type UpdatePartnerInput = z.infer<typeof updatePartnerValidator>;
export type UpdateHackerInput = z.infer<typeof updateHackerValidator>;
```

`server/src/graphql/resolvers/mutations.ts`

```
export const updateUser = async (
  _: undefined,
  // tried this as well
  // args: UpdateMentorInput | UpdatePartnerInput | UpdateHackerInput,
  args: UpdateUserInput,
  ctx: Context
) => {
  if (!updateUserValidator.parse(args)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid input');
  } else {
    console.log('valid input');
  }
  authRequest(ctx);
  console.log('args', args, Object.keys(args));
  const { userUpdate, hackerProfile, partnerProfile, mentorProfile } = args;
  // console.log('args', args);
  // console.log('here', userUpdate);

  const user = await ctx.prisma.user.update({
```

https://github.com/currenthandle/next-apollo/blob/working-state/server/src/utils/validators.ts#L76
https://github.com/currenthandle/next-apollo/blob/working-state/server/src/graphql/resolvers/mutations.ts#L28